# Can the tol argument to R's optimize(fcn,...) be used to terminate iteration when the value of fcn is close enough to its minimum?

Tags: r, optimization

I have been trying (with qualified success) to minimize a somewhat ill-behaved function using optimize. I can reliably obtain acceptable solutions, but much more slowly than need be. It would be best if optimize would stop iterating when it found a function parameter that produced a return value near the minimum. It appears that this is the intent of the `tol` argument to optimize, but I have not been able to make this work as expected. In the code below, `fcn` prints the current value of the parameter to be optimized and `fcn`'s return value `(abs(x - target))`, which has a minimum of zero.

Trial 1:

```
optimize(fcn, interval=c(0.5,1), conN=10, tmtN=10 ,ObsT=28, tol=0.007)
# 0.690983 0.513100
# 0.809017 0.373100
# 0.881966 0.214100
# 0.927051 0.079100
# 0.954915 0.046200
# 0.9647293 0.0844000
# 0.9453678 0.0099000
# 0.9430344 0.0045000   <-- Should have terminated here
# 0.9369293 0.0309000
# 0.9407011 0.0205000
# 0.9430344 0.0002000

# $minimum        $objective
# [1] 0.9430344   [1] 2e-04
```

Trial 2

```
optimize(fcn, interval=c(0.2,1), conN=10,tmtN=10,ObsT=28, tol=0.007)
# 0.5055728 0.6295000
# 0.6944272 0.5112000
# 0.8111456 0.3611000
# 0.8832816 0.2225000
# 0.927864 0.071300
# 0.9554175 0.0510000
# 0.9516505 0.0286000
# 0.9429519 0.0002000   <-- Should have terminated here
# 0.9371889 0.0342000
# 0.9462852 0.0108000
# 0.9429519 0.0099000

# $minimum        $objective
# [1] 0.9429519   [1] 0.0099
```

Also, what exactly is the termination condition for `optimize`? How is it that in Trial 2, optimize does not terminate when `fcn` returns 0.0002, but does terminate when `fcn` returns 0.0099?

Comment: Post `fcn`'s definition.

Comment: You are assuming something about the meaning of `tol`. Look in the help for `optimize` and follow the link to the Fortran code mentioned in the help. You will see that `tol` in an indirect way refers to the distance between two successive values of `x` and not to function values. Same thing in the source code for `optimize` in R: `library/stats/src/optimize.c` and look at function `Brent_fmin`.